# The Kirch topology is the same as the prime integer topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory

These topologies are defined on the set $X=\{1,2,...\}$ of positive integers and provide interesting examples of a countable space that is connected, locally connected and Hausdorff.  Notation: $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,...\}$. The topologies are defined in terms of suitable (one-sided) arithmetic progressions
$$a+\alpha\mathbb{N} = \{a,a+\alpha,a+2\alpha,...\}.$$

The **[Kirch topology](https://doi.org/10.2307/2317265)** (Amer. Math. Monthly vol. 76 (1969), pp. 169-171) is defined by taking as a [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) all sets $a+p\mathbb{N}$ with $a>0$, $p$ prime and $p>a$.  (So for example $1+2\mathbb{N}$ and $10+17\mathbb{N}$ are in the subbase, but $10+3\mathbb{N}$ is not.)

On the other hand, Steen & Seebach, *Counterexamples in Topology*, example #61 defines the **prime integer topology** in the same way, except for the condition $p>a$.  Their topology admits as a subbase all sets of the form $a+p\mathbb{N}$ with $a>0$, $p$ prime, and $p$ not dividing $a$.  Equivalenty, a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for the topology is given by all sets of the form $a+\alpha\mathbb{N}$ with $a>0$, $\alpha>0$ and squarefree, and $a$ and $\alpha$ relatively prime.

Clearly, every set in the subbase for the Kirch topology is open in the prime integer topology, so the prime integer topology is a finer topology.  Are the two topologies in fact the same?

---

**(Added Jun 6, 2022)** I realized I did not properly reflect the definition from Steen & Seebach.  In their notation, they define the prime integer topology as being generated by the subbase consisting of all sets of the form
$$U_p(b)=(b+p\mathbb{Z})\cap X,$$
with $p$ prime and not dividing $b$.  That is, the subbasic open sets are arithmetic progressions extending as far as possible in both directions (while remaining a subset of $X$). If we take $b'\equiv b\pmod p$ with $0<b'<p$, then $U_p(b)=U_p(b')=b'+p\mathbb{N}$ with $b'<p$.  So this is the same as a subbasic open set in the Kirch article.

The question whether the topologies generated by the $a+p\mathbb{N}$
described at the top with and without the condition $a<p$ are the same or not is still valid, and the answer is they are the same.

For example, the article *[The Kirch space is topologically rigid](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.12357)* by Banakh, Stelmakh, Turek takes the definition without the condition $a<p$.

Similarly the closely related [Golomb topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression_topologies) on $X$ admits as a base the collection of all sets of the form $a+\alpha\mathbb{N}$ with $a>0$, $\alpha>0$, and $a$ and $\alpha$ relatively prime.  The subcollection of such sets with the extra condition $a<\alpha$ also forms a base for the topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two topologies are the same.

Let $\tau$ denote the Kirch topology.  It's enough to show that any set $a+p\mathbb{N}$ (with $p\nmid a$) in the subbase for the prime integer topology is open in $\tau$. Take an arbitrary element $a+pn\in a+p\mathbb{N}$.  Let $a'$ be the residue of $a$ modulo $p$, so $0<a'<p$ and $a\equiv a' \pmod{p}$.  Then $a'+p\mathbb{N}$ is open in $\tau$ by definition.  Choose a prime $q$ larger than $p$ and $a+pn$.  The set $(a+pn)+q\mathbb{N}$ is open in $\tau$.  So the intersection

$$((a+pn)+q\mathbb{N})\cap(a'+p\mathbb{N})=(a+pn)+pq\mathbb{N}$$

is open in $\tau$.  That's an open nbhd of $a+pn$ contained in $a+p\mathbb{N}$.  Since $a+pn$ was arbitrary, $a+p\mathbb{N}$ is open in $\tau$.

---

Here is a more "topological" proof.  First of all, the Kirch topology $\tau$ is Haursdorff (if $a\ne b$ and $p$ is a prime larger than $a$ and $b$, $a+p\mathbb{N}$ and $b+p\mathbb{N}$ are disjoint nbhds of $a$ and $b$). So any point is closed and any finite set is closed.  Now given a set $a+p\mathbb{N}$ (with $p\nmid a$) in the subbase for the prime integer topology, let $a'$ be the residue of $a$ modulo $p$.  The set $a'+p\mathbb{N}$ is open in $\tau$.  Its subset $a+p\mathbb{N}$ differs from $a'+p\mathbb{N}$ by a finite set, so it is also open in $\tau$.